# Python Strange Issue Using File in Folder

Tags: python, authentication, login-script

I have a simple login script I am making for education.

```
def login():
    user = input("Username: ")
    paw = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ")
    f = open(r'usera.txt', "r")
    for line in f.readlines():
        us, pw = line.strip().split("|", 1)
        if (user in us) and (paw in pw):
            print("Login Successful")
            return True

def menu():
    print("Alex it worked")


def main():
    log = login()
    if log == True:
         menu()
```

Does not work it says usera.txt does not exist in the folder path, although I have my main.py and usera.txt in the same folder, but making my code like this works, why?

```
def login():
    user = input("Username: ")
    paw = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ")
    f = open(r'C:\Users\alex\pycharm\sandboxes\sandboxes\usera.txt', "r")
    for line in f.readlines():
        us, pw = line.strip().split("|", 1)
        if (user in us) and (paw in pw):
            print("Login Successful")
            return True


def menu():
    print("Alex it worked")


def main():
    log = login()
    if log == True:
         menu()
```

**Folder Structure**

- sandboxes/sandboxes.py
- sandboxes/usera.txt

but also on another note, what Am I doing wrong in order to allow any entry to pass the login screen.

```
def login():
        user = input("Username: ")
        paw = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ")
        f = open(r'usera.txt', "r")
        for line in f.readlines():
            us, pw = line.strip().split("|", 1)
            if (user in us) and (paw in pw):
                print("Login Successful")
                return True

    def menu():
        print("Alex it worked")


    def main():
        log = login()
        if log == True:
             menu()
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I am a noob, I need better error handling and also to make an else statement for improper login. What is best way to cycle back into the start of the login function?

Comment: Can you add `print(os.getcwd())` before the line your error occurs on and give us the result? Make sure you `import os`

Comment: How are you running the code?  I suspect your current working directory is the directory where the Python executable lives, not the directory where `main.py` lives.

Comment: Welcome to computers world, you just discovered what's the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is.

Comment: Just one comment - you have a bug in your code: you're using the `in` operator instead of equality check (`==`). So that typed username of `b` and password of `2` will give True for username (in the file) of `abc` and password of `123` :)

Comment: Also you said the `usera.txt` file lives in `sandboxes`, but in your full path example I can't see it!

Comment: Sorry I renamed folder paths for my post, my bad I mean it would be sitting in aa folder along with the Python file! but better yet, why is my login script allowing any entry without stopping after an in proper account.